# Shared lazyListState across multiple LazyRow result in strange behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack compose and trying to implement a scrollable data table using jetpack LazyColumn/LazyRow. The first row and first column of the entire table shall be sticky.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BaseTheme {
                ExceptionsSpreadSheet(exceptions = generateData())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity, the `BaseTheme` is just the default theme android studio generated for me.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 960, heightDp = 540)
@Composable
fun ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader(
    exception: DropBoxException = DropBoxException(),
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.DarkGray),
        state = state
    ) {
        stickyHeader {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "id")
        }
        items(1) {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "processName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageVersionCode")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageVersionName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "activity")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "romVersion")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "platformId")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "productName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "modelName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionSummary")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionType")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionDigest")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "androidId")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "occurTime")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "callStack")
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 960, heightDp = 540)
@Composable
fun ExceptionSpreadSheetRow(
    exception: DropBoxException = DropBoxException(),
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
) {
    LazyRow(state = state) {
        stickyHeader {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(
                text = exception.id.toString(),
                modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.DarkGray)
            )
        }
        items(1) {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.packageName)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.processName)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.packageVersionCode)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.packageVersionName)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.activity)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.romVersion)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.platformId.toString())
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.productName)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.modelName)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.exceptionSummary)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.exceptionType)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.exceptionDigest)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.androidId)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.occurTime.toString())
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.callStack)
        }
    }
}
```

I created a `ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader` for the sticky title, which will display some static names for columns, and a `ExceptionSpreadSheetRow` for rows below the header, each one has a sticky `id` column.

Then I combined these two components together as ``

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ExceptionsSpreadSheet(exceptions: List<DropBoxException>) {
    val sharedScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    if (sharedScrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
        sharedScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
        sharedScrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
    }
    LazyColumn {
        stickyHeader {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader(exception = exceptions.first())
            ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader(exception = exceptions.first(), state = sharedScrollState)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader(state = sharedScrollState)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetRow(exception = exceptions.first(), state = sharedScrollState)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetRow(state = sharedScrollState)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetHeaderTest(state = sharedScrollState)
            ExceptionSpreadSheetHeaderTest(exception = exceptions.first(), state = sharedScrollState)
        }
        items(exceptions) {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetRow(exception = it, state = sharedScrollState)
        }
    }
}
```

I used `sharedScrollState` to sync horizontal scroll state across columns, then I found 2 strange behavior, any help or explanation would be great for me, thanks in advance.

1. in the `items` section, the shared scroll state does not work at first, only when i added the `if (sharedScrollState.isScrollInProgress)` part, the rows in `items` would sync, otherwise it looks like [items_not_sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njpdT.gif). I would love to know why it works after I added the `if` part, or why it does not work before
2. in the `stickyHeaders` section of `ExceptionsSpreadSheet`, I added a lot of rows for testing, and the result looks like [header_not_sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I15LR.gif). The first 6 lines are headers I added, including the 2 red one as `ExceptionSpreadSheetHeaderTest`:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 960, heightDp = 540)
@Composable
fun ExceptionSpreadSheetHeaderTest(
    exception: DropBoxException = DropBoxException(),
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Red),
        state = state
    ) {
        stickyHeader {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "id")
        }
        items(1) {
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "processName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageVersionCode")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "packageVersionName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "activity")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "romVersion")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "platformId")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "productName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "modelName")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionSummary")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionType")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "exceptionDigest")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "androidId")
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = exception.occurTime.toString())
            ExceptionSpreadSheetCell(text = "callStack")
        }
    }
}
```

In the gif, only the 4th and 7th header is synced with contents below, so here are the strange behavior(s):

- in the code, the 2nd header (`ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader(exception = exceptions.first(), state = sharedScrollState)`) and the 7th header (`ExceptionSpreadSheetHeaderTest(exception = exceptions.first(), state = sharedScrollState)`) has nothing different but between the second last `ExceptionSpreadSheetCell` in there `items` section, it seems that I have to somehow use the `exception` passed in then the sync would work, that looks really strange to me.
- the 6th and 7th header differs in constructor parameters, 6th header uses default value, 7th header uses outer assigned value, but they result in different sync behavior.

The `DropBoxException` class is a simple data class

```kotlin
data class DropBoxException(
    var id: Int = 0,
    var packageName: String = "",
    var processName: String = "",
    var packageVersionCode: String = "",
    var packageVersionName: String = "",
    var activity: String = "",
    var romVersion: String = "",
    var platformId: Int = -1,
    var productName: String = "",
    var modelName: String = "",
    var exceptionSummary: String = "",
    var exceptionType: String = "",
    var exceptionDigest: String = "",
    var androidId: String = "",
    var occurTime: Int = 0,
    var callStack: String = "",
)
```

and `generateData()` create some dummy data for me

```kotlin
fun generateData(): List<DropBoxException> = (1..300).map {
    DropBoxException(
        id = it,
        packageName = "$it packageName",
        processName = "$it processName"
    )
}
```

If you beleived I mis-used some of the interfaces or the question is asked somewhere else before, feel free to post links and I'll look into them, thanks again!

Comment: You can't make two lazy views be in sync just by using the same state. Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69613111/3585796) of syncing two states.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov thanks for replying, I got inspired and posted my current solution below, hope it would help others

Answer (score 2):

After I checked bunch of examples, it's now clear to me that each row/column shall has its own state. So here is my current solution, by making each row's lazyListState listen to a mutable value, and change that value when any row scrolls

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    // ...
}

val horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex = mutableStateOf(0)
val horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset = mutableStateOf(0)

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ExceptionsSpreadSheet(exceptions: List<DropBoxException>) {
    // ...
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 960, heightDp = 540)
@Composable
fun ExceptionSpreadSheetHeader() {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
        horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
        horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
    }
    LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.DarkGray), state = scrollState) {
        // ...
    }
    LaunchedEffect(horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value, horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value) {
        Log.v("test", "launch title $horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset")
        scrollState.scrollToItem(horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value, horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 960, heightDp = 540)
@Composable
fun ExceptionSpreadSheetRow(
    exception: DropBoxException = DropBoxException(),
) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
        horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
        horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
    }
    LazyRow(state = scrollState) {
        // ...
    }
    LaunchedEffect(horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value, horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value) {
        scrollState.scrollToItem(horizontalFirstVisibleItemIndex.value, horizontalFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset.value)
    }
}
```

hope it could help anyone looking for solutions. It occurs to me with some animation lagging but good enough for my case, so I'm not digging more into this problem, but further optimization is welcomed.

Comment: @lcarcus I have tried this approach for my very similar use case but this causes sluggish scrolling and causes lots of recompositions. have u found any other alternative?